# Laravel - Create PDF file from raw content - JSON API

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

I am trying to create a temporarily PDF file from raw PDF string.

This is my input, which is sent through an API (JSON):

```
{
   "name": "pdffilename.pdf",
   "content": "%PDF-1.2 [.......]%%EOF"
}
```

- The `"content"` string is the actual PDF raw data string.

Now this is my controller, that handles the API request:

```
/**
 * Function to convert a PDF file to text
 */
public function PDFtoText(Request $request)
{
    $name = $request->name;
    $content = $request->content;

    //Save PDF file on the server (temp files).
    $pdf = Storage::disk('local')->put('/temp_files/' . $name, $content);

    return response()->json([
        'result' => "Success"
    ], 200);
}
```

An actual file is created in the `temp_files` folder, with the name `pdffilename.pdf`. However I cannot open the file, as it says the file is "corrupt".

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure that content not slashed or quoted?

Comment: A PDF cannot be send through a JSON API without being encoded with e.g. Base64. JSON uses UTF-8 encoding while the PDF is binary. So I think you already make the wrong statement about the format or the API is faulty. Also double check the name of your method: It doesn't do any PDF to text conversion.

Answer (score -1):

the best way to save the content of the document or file is using the base64_encode function, this transform de content in base64 encode. Then when you need this content the unique process you need to do is to call the base64_decode function. I tried and works fine for me. Any questions only write me.

Comment: Hi @Cristhian, I don't think the problem here is in the saving of the PDF received from the API, but rather the fact that sending a PDF without encoding (base64 encode here) it first it will not work. As far as I understand your answer you're suggesting he should save the raw PDF data in base64 encoding, but that seems to be too late... It should have been encoded before the PDF is sent over the API.

Comment: Maybe my answer not was very explicit and clear. He needs to send the content of the file encode.